# Popup notification when leaving cart while there are items in it

Tags: cart

Is there any way to create a popup notification when a customer leaves the website while there are still items in the cart?

It should contain message like: There are still items in your cart, are you sure you want to leave?

I've tried to search for any extension to realise this, but i couldn't found any.

Got any ideas? Can this be achieved by adding a code onto all pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you will need to use javascript and only trigger it if the cart contain items.

Take a look at

- [Popup box on page exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557627/popup-box-on-page-exit)
- [How to show pop-up survey with Jquery when leaving page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118722/how-to-show-pop-up-survey-with-jquery-when-leaving-page)
- [Magento How to check if the shopping cart is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779110/magento-how-to-check-if-the-shopping-cart-is-empty-or-not)